# Need help in Uv/image editor

Tags: uv

[image]

Noob here, as you see i am trying to select area which i need to be applied to mesh not whole thing but no success, any suggestions?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Could you please word it differently?

Comment: so i don't need white part as you can see on the left side not whole texture, i just want to have what  i have selected  on uv editor.

Comment: Looks like you have other UVs in there that do not show up in the UV-View because they are not selected. Those UVs might be lying outside of the area you want and so map the outside area. You could apply a different material to those verts.